# legal expression for "going insane"

Tags: expressions, legalese

in a company bylaws document, I'm trying to describe situations in which a the term of a company director can be ended. These include death, as well as "going insane" or "losing his mind" - but I'm looking for a more "PC" or "legalese" way of saying this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, I think the best EL&U could suggest is a good thesaurus, starting at "insane". Maybe the guys over on [Law.se] might have more specific answers?

Comment: I don't think that PC and legalese will necessarily produce the same answer. It's easy to think up terms, e.g. mental infirmity, loss of faculties, psychosis, etc.  You really need to tell us what the purpose of this document is. For example, a PC document will be of little use in a court of law.

Comment: Hi Chasly, Dan... Maybe "PC" isn't the right term to use. This a legal document that, like any other bylaws document, forms the basis for how a company operates, and it should be treated as such. By PC - I mean that I'm trying to avoid all of the various familiar expressions, and find an expression that can cover such cases should something be brought to court.

Comment: Maybe you should ask in law.stackexchange.com in that case.

Comment: Please just stop and get a lawyer to write it. If you really propose to strip somebody of their directorship due to a bout of mental illness, the legal ramifications for the company could be serious.

Comment: *'non compos mentis'*; but definitely what @mikeagg said. Seriously.

Comment: Hi Mikeagg- I'm not writing the bylaws from scratch. I'm translating the existing bylaws from another language into English.

Comment: Which jurisdiction would enforce these bylaws? If the company is operating in an English-speaking country and the English translation could be presented to an English-speaking court as part of a lawsuit, you really want it to have been professionally written.

Comment: I agree, mikeagg. My job is to translate the bylaws. I imagine that my client will have the English text reviewed by a competent legal authority after it is completed.

Comment: "Mentally incompetent" is probably the most common description of a nutso person.  But the conditions for determining that must be laid out to some degree (if only "as judged by a 2/3rds vote of the board" or some such).

Comment: To expand upon what Hot Licks said, "incompetence" also extends to mental retardation. So, it extends to mental illnesses which are not strictly insanity. Essentially, that would also allow you to kick Forrest Gump off your board of directors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is requesting legal advice.

Comment: @tchrist I am not asking for legal advice in any way. Maybe you misunderstood. I am asking how to say something in English. This does not constitute legal advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the related clauses which fit your needs.

(d) a registered medical practitioner who is treating that person gives a written opinion to the company stating that that person has become physically or mentally incapable of acting as a director and may remain so for **more than three months;**

(e) by reason of that person's mental health, a court makes an order which wholly or partly prevents that person from personally exercising any powers or rights which that person would otherwise have;

[I think you can use both of them above](http://www.companylawclub.co.uk/removal-of-a-director-from-office)

You can change the period from three months to a shorter peirod.

Answer (score 2):

The legal term is *non compos mentis*.

P.S. If you wanted to avoid Latin:  "not of sound mind".  It covers an array of conditions that go to the idea of being mentally unfit, whether because of insanity, daily drug stupor, or some other set of circumstances that impair judgment.